# Should you use a plural verb if you refer to a fraction?

Tags: verbs

Should you use a plural verb if you refer to a fraction?

> Nine tenths of the pillar *have* rotted away.

I think *has* should be used here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The fraction is considered a singular quantity, just as the plural "20 ml" in "Twenty milliliters of reagent **was** added to the culture medium" and the plural "US$5" in "Five American dollars **is** a lot to pay for something like that". Ergo, "Nine tenths of the pillar **has** rotted away" is correct.

Comment: @BillFranke: You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @Bill Franke's comment is wrong. A fraction has the same plurality as the thing it modifies. "Nine tenths of the pillar has rotted away", but "nine tenths of the *pillars have* fallen down".

Comment: @Peter: My comment may be **incomplete**, Peter, but it isn't "wrong". And you have no references. It answers the OP's question (& I've turned it into an answer, so now it's a **complete** referenced answer). Just last week, by the way, I was chided for giving the OP more than was asked for. Had the OP asked about "nine tenths of the **pillars has** fallen down", rest assured that I would have said it was grammatically incorrect. I hope you don't believe that I think otherwise. Notice, please that my comment says "_just **as the plural '20 ml'** in_ [a similar S]".

Comment: Bill: I agree; I should have said incomplete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fraction is considered a singular quantity *in this particular sentence*, just as the plural *20 ml* in "Twenty milliliters of reagent was added to the culture medium" and the plural *US$5* in "Five American dollars is a lot to pay for something like that". Ergo, "Nine tenths of the pillar has rotted away" is correct.

Here's what one grammar "expert" says:

> [Rule 9](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)
>   "With words that indicate portions—percent, fraction, part, majority, some, all, none, remainder, and so forth —look at the noun in your of phrase (object of the preposition) to determine whether to use a singular or plural verb. If the object of the preposition is singular, use a singular verb. If the object of the preposition is plural, use a plural verb.
>
> Examples:
>
> > Fifty percent of the pie has disappeared.
> >     Pie is the object of the preposition of.
> >     Fifty percent of the pies have disappeared.
> >     Pies is the object of the preposition.
> >     One-third of the **city is** unemployed.
> >     One-third of the **people are** unemployed."
>
> [My emphasis. "City" is singular, as is "pillar"; "people" is plural, but "pillar" is not: it would be were it "pillars", but that ain't the case.]

[Another "authority"](http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/agreement.html) says this:

> **Fractions** and percentages
>
> Fractions and percentages take the singular when they modify a mass noun and the plural when they modify a plural noun; either the singular or the plural may be used when they modify a collective noun.
>
> > Fifty percent [*Can be replaced by **nine-tenths***] of those children have psychological problems.
> >
> > One-half [*Can be replaced by **nine-tenths***] of the cake has been eaten." [Italicized words in square brackets are my editorial additions.]

This kind of structure is one of those hotly contested usages that twist the brow and carpals as they twist the subarachnoid cerebellar noodles as if they were merely British knickers or American panties. I recommend a cold shower for anyone who suffers from this fractional syndrome.

Comment: I liked the link. +1 for that.

Answer (score 10):

Largely ditto on BillFranke. Let me add an additional clarification.

When we are talking about a group of many objects, and we are now taking some fraction of that total number, like "50% of Hungarians" or "two-thirds of the buildings in Toledo", we use a plural verb. This makes sense, because the number is normally expected to be more than one. If we have a group of 100 people and we take 3/4 of them, that's 75 people. "50% of Hungarians are ..." Etc.

When we are talking about a portion of a single object, like "half of Hungary" or "two-thirds of the building", we use a singular verb. "Half of Hungary is ..."

The example brought up in the comments of "$5 is a lot to pay" is a different case. When you discuss a quantity as a quantity, rather than as a collection of objects, you use the singular. For example, "20 members are voting for the rules change", but "20 members is the minimum number required to approve a rules change". In the first case we are talking about a group of people, so it's plural. In the second case we are talking about the number as a number, so it's singular.

Comment: Since _20 members_ is not a number (a number is inherently unitless), "20 is the minimum number of members required..." might be a better way to say this.

Comment: Yes, it's technically true that "20 members" is not a number, it's a number plus a unit of measure. When I was writing the above I struggled for the right word, because I'm not aware of a word that means "a number plus a unit of measure". A "quantity", perhaps?

Comment: And oh, okay, you could quibble that "20 members is the minimum number ..." is flawed for the reasons you state. But I think that's a pretty pedantic objection: the meaning is clear, and people say this all the time.

Comment: If a value like $5 is being used as a single quantity, it should take a singular verb.  On the other hand, if someone was annoyed at the number of times he had to pay $1, one could reasonably say that "He thought five dollars were a lot to pay"; note that in the latter case, it may be reasonable to write "...5 dollars were..." but not "...$5 were...".

Comment: @supercat Arguably valid, but no one says that. It's always "Five dollars was a lot to pay." People DO say, "He laid five one dollar bills on the counter", but now we're talking about five pieces of paper, not the amount of money per se. You might say, "Five one-dollars charges were a lot", or something else that expressed the idea that these were five separate one-dollar transactions.

Comment: @Jay: I would only expect a construct like "five dollars were a lot" in specific contexts where the term "dollar" was *already* frequently being used to refer to an individual monetary instrument or transaction.  If in context the term "dollar" has already been used a dozen times to describe an individual item, then it may be reasonable to use the term directly as a countable noun.  A lot depends upon context, though.

Comment: @supercat Okay, possible given the right context. I'll concede.