# plural/singular question

Tags: grammar, verbs, plural-forms, singular

Can I use singular verb for these sentences?

Sentence 1. "Twenty gallons of paint is needed to paint the house"

Sentence 2. "Three members of the staff/crew is needed to paint the house"

Note

I know there are other threads with similar questions so plaese don't mark this as duplicate as I'm asking a particular questions in this thread.

Edit.
I'm in cofusion because the first example has a mass/uncountable noun and the second example has a singular noun and from what it says [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318501/question-about-singular-plural-with-present-perfect?noredirect=1#comment724598_318501) it should be singular verb because it says the following: "Generally speaking - though there are exceptions - the fraction takes the same plurality as the thing it modifies; see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/should-you-use-a-plural-verb-if-you-refer-to-a-fraction) for a good explanation." so I don´t know if the sentences need a singular or plural verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Twenty gallons of paint **is** needed to paint the house.

is fine. *Twenty gallons of paint* would be considered a singular unit, as you said. However:

> Twenty one gallon cans of paint **are** needed to paint the house.

is clearly plural.

> 2. **Three** members of the crew **are** need to paint the house.

Even though you are referring to part of the crew, the number in the example is *three*, so I would not use the fraction rule. You could use a fraction though:

> Half of the members of the crew is needed to paint the house.

*half* is a fixed group and has a set value based on the size of the crew.

Comment: Based on what "sounds right" in British English, I would prefer "Half of the crew *is* needed" but "Half of the members of the crew *are* needed". The plural "members" following the singular "half" seems to take precedence.

Answer (score 5):

In the first, I would probably say "are", but I would accept "is" as perfectly grammatical, treating "twenty gallons of" as a quantifier on the non-countable noun "paint".

In the second, I would accept only "are", because "Three members of" cannot be a quantifier on "crew" or "staff". If you said "The three-strong crew" I would accept "is", though I would still say "are" myself.

Comment: Please check my edition for more information. Thanks

Comment: I have given you my answer, and I don't see any reason to change it, except to note that in British English "staff" and "crew" can be plural or singular any way. I believe that in American English the pundits object to "staff" or "crew" with a plural verb.

Comment: Sir I wasn't telling you to change your answer I was just telling you check new information. Thanks you anyway sir.

Comment: +1. To me, it seems like it depends on the emphasis of your sentence: (1:) "gallons" / "are",  "paint" / "is", (2:) "members" / "are". Realistically, I would use /"will be" or /"would be" for both sentences.